# Wineglass Sound

Tags: frequency

The sound that is produced from wineglasses, are they longitudinal or transverse waves? I know that sound waves are longitudinal, but have heard from someone that the waves produced from wineglasses are transverse. Is this true? Or do they mean that the vibration from wineglasses were transverse?

Comment: You answered well already, I'd say. 
There are no transverse sound waves (since air does not resist shearing at all, only stretching).
And the motion of the wineglass is probably mostly transverse (since it is easier to move a thin layer in the transverse direction, and nearly not possible in the tangential)

Answer (score 3):

The wineglass does vibrate in a transverse mode, deforming from a circle to a elliptical elongating first in one direction then the perpendicular direction repeatedly.  Here is a [short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5VZcY1B8iPM) and a [peak](https://www.deepdyve.com/lp/american-association-of-physics-teachers/in-vino-veritas-a-study-of-wineglass-acoustics-8LJRyRSfUO) at the classic article ”In Vino Veritas – A study of wineglass acoustics” A.P French, Am. J. Phys., Vol.51, No.
8, August 1983.